# "Unexpected character after line continuation character" error

Tags: python, arcgis

I have read a few answers about the same error message, but don't understand how they apply to my code. I have no clue what is wrong with it. I'm exporting a model from `ArcGIS` to Python. My model is validated in `ArcMap`, but when I export the code I get the message.

## Local variables:

```
PopulationEllipse_Buffered = "C:\\GIS_Cert\\GIS211\\FinalProject\\FinalLongmont.gdb\\PopulationEllipse_Buffered"
PopulationEllipse_Buffered_w_New_Field = PopulationEllipse_Buffered
PopulationEllipse_Buffered_w_Ranks = PopulationEllipse_Buffered_w_New_Field
```

## Process: Add Field (3)

```
arcpy.AddField_management(PopulationEllipse_Buffered, "PopRank", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
```

## Process: Calculate Field (3)

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(PopulationEllipse_Buffered_w_New_Field, "PopRank", "calculateIF( !ToBufDist! )", "PYTHON", "def calculateIF(dist):\n if(dist == 0):\n return 5\n elif(dist == 0.5):\n return 4\n else:\n return 3")

print(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
```

Comment: Is it possible that the new line characters do not need to be escaped and that at the end of each line you are leaving an unintended "\"?

Comment: The code above is exactly how it exports from modelbuilder in ArcMap, and how it appears in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your function string is not valid Python because the clauses of the `if` statement are not indented:

```
def calculateIF(dist):
 if(dist == 0):
 return 5
 elif(dist == 0.5):
 return 4
 else:
 return 3
```

Those `return` statements need to be indented further than the `if`/`elif`/`else` are (e.g. add another space before the `return`s and after the `\n`s). But the error message you're getting is not the one I'd expect if that were the problem you're running into.

Comment: So I checked the codeblock on the model, and the returns are indented.  I hit return on the code in Pycharm, and did this (the $ is where I placed code on a new line by hitting return, The $$ means I indented further):$"def calculateIF(dist):\\n  "
                                $"if(dist == 0):\\n    "
                                    $$"return 5\\n  "
                                $"elif(dist == 0.5):\\n    "
                                    $$"return 4\\n  "
                                $"else:\\n    "
                                    $$"return 3")  Same error message.

Comment: So the Calculate Field Example 3 here https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm is what I just tried.  Pasted the if statement in as codeblock=, removed the expression, and put it in as 'codeblock' in the string.  Now I get "NameError: name 'calculateIF' is not defined".

Answer (score 0):

So my professor doesn't know why this error happens with the codeblock, but the solution is to remove it and do several select by attributes and after each calculate the field with the selections.